# Resharper es6 default parameter support

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ecmascript-6, resharper

Is there any way to allow VisualStudio/Resharper to support ES6 default function parameters syntax, such as:

```
function foo(val="2000") {

 }
```

I´ve already setup Resharper´s javascript language level to ECSMA6, and most things are working fine, but still I get an **"Expected '{'"** syntax error for the default parameters scenario

Any extensions required?

I´m running on Vs2015 update 2 and Resharper 2016.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like disabling VS2015 validation did the trick, letting Resharper handle ES6 validation himself

[image]